# Catch a Dynamo Stream Event locally with serverless offline

Tags: serverless-framework

I am trying to debug on visual studio code a dynamo stream event handler . Can I connect my local serverless offline program with streams of a deployed DynamoBD ? I have tried many ways but my handler was not triggered .

At the moment I am using serverless-offline-dynamodb-streams and I have added:

```
Plugins
- serverless-offline-dynamodb-streams 
- serverless-offline
```

And I have connected my function to the remote resource (arn):

```
functions:
  myKinesisHandler:
    handler: handler.compute
    events:
      - stream:
          enabled: true
          type: dynamodb
          arn: arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-1:XXXXXX:table/myStream/stream/2018-07-02T19:48:31.121
          batchSize: 10
          startingPosition: TRIM_HORIZON
```

And added the following custom configuration :

```
custom:
  serverless-offline-dynamodb-streams:
    apiVersion: '2013-12-02'
    endpoint: http://0.0.0.0:8000
    region: eu-west-1
    accessKeyId: root
    secretAccessKey: root
    skipCacheInvalidation: false
    readInterval: 500
```

I am running my application with:

```
sls offline
```

But still I did not manage to have my handler triggered .. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there's no way to proxy a DDB stream event to your local Serverless Offline server. AWS controls that integration entirely.

Occasionally when I face this issue I:

1. Verify that the lambda is being properly triggered by the DDB stream event
2. If so, copy the stream event that I was expecting to see and save it as a JSON file
3. Use `sls invoke local --data "{yourJSON}"` to manually trigger your lambda function (docs [here](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/cli-reference/invoke-local/)).

From there you should be able to debug.